# How to set TUN/TAP devices

Tags: vpn

I know that similar questions have been asked before and I did try to follow the instructions suggested by other users, but I still can't seem to solve my problem.
I just signed up for HMA vpn. When I run the script they provided I get stopped at the last hurdle

Calling OpenVPN as service...
Options error: You must define TUN/TAP device (--dev)
Use --help for more information.

I don't know what to do.. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) was tremendously helpful to me in setting up OpenVPN.  I assume you are running it as a client?  Of course, I do not know what configuration steps you have already performed, but it is likely that you need to edit your profile file `?.ovpn` to, as a minimum, include the hostname of the server you are trying to connect to.  Then, depending on the client you are using, you can either merge the certificates and keys into `?.ovpn` or supply them separately.  Step 4 in the linked article goes over this in detail.  Then step 5 shows how to incorporate the profile into a number of different client systems (IOS, OSX, Windows).

Comment: Thank you for the guide. I got a better understanding of the process, however, still no luck. Now I can only connect to the server in Texas that the guide sets up..

Comment: I'm assuming you have the correct server in the line `remote my-server-1 1194`?  If you can connect to anything, your config is working to some extent.  Maybe your keys and certificates are not right for the server you are trying to access.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307503/16920 with a case example.